# Image processing - Reduce object thickness without removing

Tags: c#, algorithm, language-agnostic, image-processing

I have an image like below.

What I want is a monochrome image such that white parts are kept white, the rest is black. However, the tricky part is that I also want to reduce the white parts to be one pixel in thickness.

It's the second part that I'm stuck with.
My first thought was to do a simple threshold, then use a sort of "Game of Life" type iterative process where a white pixel was removed if it had neighbours on one side but not the other (i.e. it's an edge) however I have a feeling this would reduce ends of lines to nothing over time so I'd end up with a blank image.

What algorithm can I use to get the image I want, given the original image?

<sup>(My language of choice is C#, but anything is fine)</sup>

---

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Comment: Maybe you can add a restriction: Don't delete a white pixel if it has < 3 white pixel neighbors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After detecting the morphological extended maxima of a given height:

[image]

and then thinning gives:

[image]

You can also manipulate the height parameter, or prune the thinned image.

Code in Mathematica:

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPtl6.png"],  "Grayscale"];
max = MaxDetect[img, .55]
Thinning[max]
```

*EDIT* I followed my own advice and a height of .4 gives segments which are more precisely localized:

[image]

Comment: That looks almost exactly what I want. I don't have Mathematica (and don't want to buy it just for this). What algorithm does it use?

Comment: For some reason I can not edit my previous comment. For a description of the extended maxima: P. Soille, "Morphological Image Analysis". For the thinning, right now I don't know what algorithm is used exactly; it is an iterative process which looks at 3x3 neighborhood around each white pixel and decide whether to blacken it or not -- ie., a version of the "Game of life" you mentioned. There is a description of thinning here: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm

Comment: For thinning, two common algorithms are Stentiford and Zhang-Suen. The free version of the app WinTopo has implementations of each; the app includes useful smoothing options for raster-to-vector conversion. For thresholding you might also consider a local threshold such as "moving average" or the like; some thread-like features may be visible to the eye but eliminated by a global threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look into Binary Morphological transformations such as Erosion and Dilation. Graphics libraries such as OpenCV() http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ and that statistical/matrix tool Gnu Octave http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/bwmorph.html support these operations.